# Two step subfolder to include javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, include-path

How to include deep folder in ruby on rails.

The norman subfolder //= require subfolder/filename how do make it

```
 --javascript
    -- subfolder
       --subfolder
```

two step sub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like how you think it should be

```
//= require subfolder/subfolder/filename
```

Comment: I try this one, but first it was errorin Sprockets: but now it is working. I typo the folder name.
Thanks.